# chrome.notifications.onClosed not executing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating notifications for my application using chrome.notifications API. After reading through the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/notifications/#method-clear), I saw a method called `onClosed` which should execute a function once a user or system closes the notification. However, upon closing the notification, my listener is not firing.

Here is my `background.js`

```js
// this doesnt work for some reason
chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener((id) => {
  console.log("Clear Notification:", id)
  chrome.notifications.clear(id, result => {
    if (result) {
      console.log("Notification was cleared")
    } else {
      console.log("Notification not cleared")
    }
  })
})


// This works everytime without fail. Only executes when the notification is clicked. 
// Does not fire if the 'close' button is clicked
chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener((id) => {
  console.log("CLICKED")
  console.log(id)
})
```

**UPDATE**

After looking at the functions available in `onClosed`, I found a function called `dispatch` which after calling actually executes the listener function in `onClosed`. In this case, at least now I now that the addListener function is there, but is just not executing when the notification is closed.

```js
// executes the listener function, but does not have the notification id
chrome.notifications.onClosed.dispatch();
```

Comment: Might be a bug in Chrome. You can report it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: I have already encountered this type of problem only with Opera browser.
I reported this to Opera support but I have not received any response. Does this happen to you with Chrome?

Comment: Yeah this is happening to me in chrome

Comment: I'm trying to debug by looking at the chrome.notifications.onClosed functions, but when I try to look at the arguments, it says `Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions` Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: Hold on, I have read wrong, sorry. What you have written as commet above onClicked event is true. Clicking on close button sholud fire only onclose event... so it's a normal behavior. If you want to close the notification also with a generic click on notification area try chrome.notifications.clear inside onClicked event.

Comment: Furthermore closing the same notification inside the onClose event could throw an error (I think)

Comment: That is a solution I was thinking of as well since it does work. However, I would like it if a user actually clicks the close button -> 'x' , since it would make more sense that way. Also if a user clicks the 'x' button, then the onClicked function does not fire.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232716/discussion-between-robbi-and-pythonnovice).